# Does $M = \sum_{k} \mathbf u_k \mathbf v_k^{\top}$ imply $\mathbf u_k \in \operatorname{colspan}(M)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Let $M = \sum_{k} \mathbf u_k \mathbf v_k^{\top}$, where both sets of vectors $\{\mathbf u_k\}$, $\{\mathbf v_k\}$ are linearly independent.

Can we conclude that $\mathbf u_k \in \operatorname{colspan}(M)$?

**Some comments:** Maybe this is trivial (it's just late here). I guess since the $\mathbf v_k$ are independent, we can multiply on the right by $V^{-1}$ (pseudo-inverse) to obtain $U$ as linear combinations of columns of $M$? Maybe that's all that's needed here. In any case me asking here is just to confirm my intuition on this?

For context, I'm trying to show that a certain maximum likelihood problem has a certain solution, which is actually a stable local maximum. The local stability condition I have derived depends on this "lemma", but I don't think it makes sense to go deeper into that here.

Comment: Why the close vote?

Comment: This question--no context nor effort shown on your part--does not meet the MSE Guidelines. You have been here long enough to know that we are NOT a Homework Answering Service! -1 and Vote-To-Close

Comment: Please edit telling us where this question came from and what you tried yourself

Comment: @Mike Why would you think this is "homework"? It's not, it's from my work. I'm trying to show that a certain maximum likelihood problem has a certain solution, which is actually a stable local maximum. The local stability condition I have derived depends on this "lemma".

Comment: Though maybe this is trivial (it's just late here). I guess since the $\mathbf v_k$ are independent, we can multiply on the right by $V^{-1}$ (pseudo-inverse) to obtain $U$ as linear combinations of columns of $M$ ? Maybe that's all that's needed here.  In any case me asking here is just to confirm my intuition on this, is that really something that is outside the guidelines?

Comment: Yes it is, this site is bombarded with low-quality "do my homework for me" questions and it makes many of us salty. Also, the question-answer for your post on MSE isn't just for you, it is also for anyone else who may come along and view your post. Please edit your OP in light of what you wrote above and I will take away my  downvote and Vote-To-Close.

Comment: @Mike I've added some more comments on the post. What were you answering with "Yes it is,"? That my question is outside guidelines? Or that it is trivial (and true)?

Comment: Yes it *was* outside guidelines [take a [tour]], thankyou for the edits. It--the math question itself--does not seem trivial to me at least, I would have to think some more of this

Comment: Sorry can you be a bit more concrete about which guideline it *was* violating? As I said, it's not homework (though it seems you assumed it was, even though there was no indication of that). It's a pretty straightforward statement, that is either true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose a vector $\mathbf w$ orthogonal to all the $\mathbf v_k$ for $k\ne i$ and *not* orthogonal to $\mathbf v_i$. (This is possible precisely because the $\mathbf v_k$ are linearly independent.) Then $M\mathbf w$ is a nonzero multiple of $\mathbf u_i$. This is a less fancy way of stating what you were already thinking. Linear independence of the $\mathbf u_k$ is not required.